# MapView not Showing annotation

Tags: mapkit, mkannotation

My MapView doesn't show annotations, following is my code. I am new to objective-c. Can someone figure out whats wrong with this code. I want to show user location with blue circle and another location with a red pin.

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>
#import <MapKit/MapKit.h>
#import <CoreLocation/CoreLocation.h>


@interface MapViewController : UIViewController                   <UIApplicationDelegate,CLLocationManagerDelegate,MKMapViewDelegate,UITextFieldDelegate>{

    CLLocationManager *locationManager;
    IBOutlet MKMapView *mapView;
}

@property (strong, nonatomic) UIWindow *window;
@property (nonatomic,retain) IBOutlet MKMapView *mapView;

@end

#import "MapViewController.h"

@implementation MapViewController
@synthesize mapView;

- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
    self.mapView.delegate = self;
    locationManager = [[CLLocationManager alloc] init];
    [locationManager setDelegate:self];
    [locationManager setDistanceFilter:kCLDistanceFilterNone];
    [locationManager setDesiredAccuracy:kCLLocationAccuracyBest];
    [self.mapView setShowsUserLocation:YES]
    [self.window makeKeyAndVisible];

    CLLocationCoordinate2D annotationCoord;
    annotationCoord.latitude = -37.5498;
    annotationCoord.longitude = -143.869;
    MKPointAnnotation *annotationPoint = [[MKPointAnnotation alloc] init];
    annotationPoint.coordinate = annotationCoord;
    annotationPoint.title = @"BlackHill PS";
    [mapView addAnnotation:annotationPoint];
}
@end
```

Comment: Does the blue dot appear?  Zoom out and look at the whole world.  Where are you expecting the annotation?  Those coordinates are in the middle of the South Pacific Ocean.  If it's supposed to be in Australia, the longitude should be +143.

Comment: yes you are right, longitude should be +143. I have changed the coordinates but still can't see any blue dot on the whole map.

Comment: It sounds like the map view IBOutlet is not connected.  In the xib/storyboard, make sure the map view is connected to the mapView outlet in the view controller.  By the way, why do you have a UIWindow in that vc?  That should only be set up in the app delegate.

Comment: yup, my mapView IBOutlet was not connected. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You are adding the annotation to the map, but you are not doing anything to make sure that the region displayed by the map is a region that includes the place marked by the annotation. Do that.

Example:

```
MKCoordinateRegion reg =
    MKCoordinateRegionMakeWithDistance(annotationPoint.coordinate, 600, 600);
mapView.region = reg;
```

By the way, all that stuff with the location manager is a complete waste as far as your code is concerned. If the map is asked to show the user's location, it will do it. Your location manager is not doing anything in the story (as far as the code you've actually shown is concerned). It isn't even running (doing updates). It's pointless.

Comment: Well, then you're doing or omitting something else that causes the problem. My code does work, and you _will_ want to do something like it. Here's my downloadable example showing how to add an annotations with varying degrees of customization: https://github.com/mattneub/Programming-iOS-Book-Examples/blob/master/bk2ch21p744maps/ch34p1008maps/ViewController.m And here's my example where we show the user's location: https://github.com/mattneub/Programming-iOS-Book-Examples/blob/master/bk2ch21p761userLocationAndGeocoding/ch34p1024userLocationAndGeocoding/ViewController.m